# Why do a number of Jedi Masters have beards?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

I have noticed that a large number of male Jedi have facial hair if they are a Jedi Master or higher. **Is there a reason for why a lot of Jedi have beards if they are Jedi Masters or higher?**

For those that want some examples:

- [Qui Gon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn?file=Qui-Gon_Jinn_Headshot_TPM.jpg)
- [Dooku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku?file=Dooku_Headshot.jpg)
- [Luke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker?file=LukeTLJ.jpg)
- [Ki-Adi-Mundi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi?file=KiAdiMundi.jpg)

Comment: Gentlemen wear beards.

Comment: No real source for an answer, but there is a more general stereotype that men with beards are wiser / more powerful.  I suspect this is just an extension of that aesthetic, since Jedi are generally seen as both wise and powerful

Comment: I suspect this is a case of tali-wag-dog. Obi-Wan (ANH) had a beard and cloak because he was living as a hermit on Tattoine. When they made the prequels, they depicted Obi-Wan in the same cloak (which morphed into the "Jedi uniform") and with a beard so you'll recognise his progression from Padawan to Master over the three films.

Comment: I think the counterpositive question whether Padawans and Knights are not allowed to wear beards since it appears as if only Masters do so will prove less assertive and a better fit since less opinionated and more specific.

Comment: If we're looking for an in universe reason it's possible that they do it due to the heavy restrictions on jedi hair styles (such as the padawan braids) and clothing (you get a brown robe, you get a brown robe) a beard might be the only way that a jedi can express themselves fashion wise

Comment: a look at the last Jedi Council and known masters from the prequel / clone wars era would show that the assumption that most masters have beards is a faulty one and I would also agree w/ @Valorum's take

Comment: "Well, this is what we look like. Some of us. Others look different."

Comment: The Jedi are a symbol of civilization. Shaving is a form of barberism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the Star Wars wikia as a reference (I know, shoot me) we have the following "notable" [Jedi Masters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Master).

- [Stass Allie](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stass_Allie) - No beard
- [Depa Billaba](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Depa_Billaba) - No beard
- [Ima-Gun Di](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ima-Gun_Di) - No beard
- [Dooku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku) - Beard
- [Cin Drallig](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cin_Drallig) - No beard
- [Sta-Den Eekin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sta-Den_Eekin) - No beard
- [Selrahc Eluos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Selrahc_Eluos) - Unknown
- [Kit Fisto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kit_Fisto) - No beard
- [Adi Gallia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Adi_Gallia) - No beard
- [Halsey](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Halsey) - No beard
- [Qui-Gon Jinn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn) - Beard
- [Coleman Kcaj](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coleman_Kcaj) - No beard
- [Kirak Infil'a](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kirak_Infil%27a) - Beard
- [Coleman Trebor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coleman_Trebor) - No beard
- [Obi-Wan Kenobi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi) - Beard
- [Ka-Moon Kholi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ka-Moon_Kholi) - Unknown
- [Ki-Adi-Mundi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi) - Beard
- [Plo Koon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Plo_Koon) - No beard
- [Pong Krell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pong_Krell) - Beard
- [Eeth Koth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eeth_Koth) - No beard
- [Agen Kolar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Agen_Kolar) - No beard
- [Cherff Maota](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cherff_Maota) - Beard
- [Jocasta Nu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jocasta_Nu) - No beard
- [Even Piell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Even_Piell) - No beard
- [Yarael Poof](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yarael_Poof) - No beard
- [Oppo Rancisis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Oppo_Rancisis) - Beard
- [Bolla Ropal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bolla_Ropal) - No beard
- [Aayla Secura](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aayla_Secura) - No beard
- [Shadday Potkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shadday_Potkin) - No beard
- [J'oopi Shé](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/J%27oopi_Sh%C3%A9) - No beard
- [Sifo-Dyas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sifo-Dyas) - No beard
- [Tera Sinube](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tera_Sinube) - No beard
- [Luke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker) - Beard
- [Shaak Ti](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shaak_Ti) - No beard
- [Saesee Tiin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Saesee_Tiin) - No beard
- [Tholme](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tholme) - No beard
- [Tiplar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tiplar) - No beard
- [Tiplee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tiplee) - No beard
- [Luminara Unduli](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luminara_Unduli) - No beard
- [Uvell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Uvell) - Unknown
- [Quinlan Vos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Quinlan_Vos) - No beard
- [Mace Windu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mace_Windu) - No beard
- [Yaddle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yaddle) - No beard
- [Yoda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda) - No beard

That tallies to 32 without beards, 9 beards and 3 unknowns. I think it's safe to say your assumption that most/a lot have beards is incorrect.

Restricting this to males only still puts this at 21 no beards, 9 beards and 3 unknowns which still challenges your assumption.

Comment: You make a good point, but I'm not sure it's fair to include women on the list (especially as the question specifically mentions males).

Comment: @Nolimon Technically none human females may be able to grow a beard, as can human woman to be fair, but I missed that the question said males so will update.